# How does one redirect %temp% in batch file to a text file?

Tags: batch-file, echo, pipe, temp

This is the line that I have in a batch file:

```
echo InstallPath="%temp%\\~tmp.B1FPXLAEP" > file.txt
```

I would like content to stay the same, but when I run the batch file, it adds the full location of the %temp% folder.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note, you are using redirection, not a pipe

Answer (score 3):

```
echo InstallPath="%%temp%%\~tmp.B1FPXLAEP" > file.txt
```

with `%` you [escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) `%`